# Webpack custom plugin. Insert attribute in react component with AST

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

I need to insert data-attr to react component at webpack compilation time. 
For example I have this component:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div>bla bla</div>
  );
};
```

And after compilation I need this:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div data-attr="some data">bla bla</div>
  );
};
```

I have wrote following plugin(which I think is almost complete, but I can not find a way to insert attribute):

```
export class ReactAttrGeneratorPlugin implements webpack.Plugin {
  public apply({ hooks }: webpack.Compiler) {

    hooks.compilation.tap(
      "ReactAttrGeneratorPlugin",
      (compilation) => {
        compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
        compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(ConstDependency, new ConstDependency.Template());
      });

    hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('ReactAttrGeneratorPlugin', (factory) => {
      factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap('ReactAttrGeneratorPlugin', (parser, options) => {
        parser.hooks.statement.tap('ReactAttrGeneratorPlugin', (statement:any) => {
          if (this.isOwnComponent(parser) && statement.type === 'ReturnStatement') {

            const div = statement.argument.arguments[0];

            /** What do I need here, to insert attribute to div? **/

          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  private isOwnComponent(parser: any) {
    return parser.state &&
      parser.state.module &&
      parser.state.module.resource.indexOf('node_modules') === -1 &&
      parser.state.module.resource.endsWith('tsx');
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never written plugins for webpack myself, but I am currently struggeling with configuring them, that's how I stumbled upon your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not written a webpack plugin myself yet, but I found https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/538 and [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inject-attributes-plugin) which seems to do something what related. The [source code of that package](https://github.com/dyw934854565/html-webpack-inject-attributes-plugin/blob/master/index.js) might be helpful for you, since it adds an attribute to *any* tag by using the following function

```
function addAttr(compilation, tags, key, val) {
    if (!tags || !tags.length) {
        return;
    }
    forEach(tags, function (tag, index) {
        var value = val;
        if (typeof val === "function") {
            value = val(tag, compilation, index);
        } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
            value = JSON.stringify(val);
        }
        tag.attributes[key] = value;
    });
}
```