# How to get image dimensions in React on compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to get the size of an image (width/height in pixels) in a React app that was created with `create-react-app`. Basically, I am looking for an equivalent to `getimagesize` in PHP.

Is there a way to get it before the image is loaded/rendered into the browser, for example during app compilation so that I can simply write `<img src={img.src} width={img.width} height={img.height} alt="" />`?

I tried using [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) but I am not sure how to properly implement it into this simple React app and therefore get errors about `fs`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should search how to do it in `webpack` as `create-react-app` uses `webpack` .
The module you looked at is fine, but you would need to use it as a `webpack` plugin.

Comment: Looks like `create-react-app` doesn't let you configure `webpack` to add plugins, might have to use `craco` or `react-app-rewired`
[https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/99]

Comment: You can use `eject` command to get to the webpack config

Comment: Alright. Let's say I got control of webpack config. How do I put `image-size` stuff into it? And what do I subsequently write in my React component that will allow me to get `img.width` and `img.height`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011241/webpack-custom-plugin-insert-attribute-in-react-component-with-ast

Comment: Nice, thanks! Getting somewhere! I ended up using `create-react-app` without `eject`, then `react-app-rewired` to write a webpack config and used `html-webpack-plugin` and `html-webpack-inject-attributes-plugin` to add `width` and `height` attributes to all `img` tags. However, running into [an error](https://codepen.io/vadimh/pen/eYMBygO?editors=0010) on compile now. Any tips?